# Cubic Equations over Function Fields or Rings

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have a question regarding the Weierstrass-type cubic equation

$$
Y^2 = 4 X^3 - g_2(z) X - g_3(z),
$$

where the functions $g_2(z)$ and $g_3(z)$ belong to some function field $\mathcal{F}$ or ring $\mathcal{R}$. For example, $\mathcal{F}$ can be the
field $\mathbb{C}(z)$ of rational functions and $\mathcal{R}$ the ring $\mathbb{C}[z]$ of polynomials (or, even, $\mathcal{F}$ can be the
field of meromorphic functions and $\mathcal{R}$ the ring of entire functions).

Naturally, one can consider the associated Diophantine-type problem, namely to look for solutions $X = X(z)$, $Y = Y(z)$ belonging to the field
$\mathcal{F}$ or to the ring $\mathcal{R}$.

Is there any literature on such problems? For example, is there a Mordell-type or a Siegel-type theorem?

Comment: Silverman's "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" has a chapter on elliptic surfaces. That is a nice place to start. And yes, there is a lot of literature on that problem....

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you suggest some paper(s)? Is there an analog to Mordell's Theorem?

Comment: Actually, Chapter III of Silverman's "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" seems very relevant to my question! Thanks again.